# ASP.NET MVC4 Remember login password using cookies - Secure way?

Tags: cookies, authentication, passwords, asp.net-mvc-4

I would like the feature for the sign in box to have the username and password automatically filled in if the user has previously been on the site and logged in successfully before. I see this implemented on many sites so I figured theres a way to do this without creating a security risk.

EDIT: According to a post this is a browser feature and should not be implemented in code because its never safe to store password anywhere.

Edited the code to reflect a new direction where Im only storing the username. However, Im not sure what to look for to see if its working. I tried to login then logout, then go to login screen again but username box still blank when the view loads in. Not sure if its the code or Im testing it the wrong way.

Login POST:

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);                    
                return Json(new { ok = true, message = "Login successful." });
            }
        }

        return Json(new { ok = false, message = "The username or password you entered is invalid. Please try again." });
    }
```

Login GET:

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Login(string path)
    {
        LoginModel model = new LoginModel();

        HttpCookie authCookie = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName.ToString()];
        if (authCookie != null)
        {
            FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);
            if (authTicket != null & !authTicket.Expired)
            {
                model.UserName = authTicket.UserData;
            }
        }

        return PartialView(path, model);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are couple of issues with your code. The first one is that you are adding the cookie to the Request object instead of adding it to the Response => `Response.Cookies.Add(authCookie);`.

The second issue is that you are creating a non-persistent cookie meaning that it will only live through the browser session. Once the user closes the browser it will be gone forever because it was never stored on the client computer. In order to create a [persistent cookie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Persistent_cookie) you need to specify an expiration date for it which will obviously correspond for how long this cookie will be persisted on the client computer. For example if you wanted to remember for 5 days:

```
HttpCookie authCookie = new HttpCookie("authCookie", "cookieValue")
{
    Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(5)
};
```

Another issue is that you are storing only the MD5 hash of the password inside the cookie and you expect to be able to decrypt it later with `FormsAuthentication.Decrypt` which is not possible. This method can decrypt values that were encrypted with the `Encrypt` method.

And the biggest problem of them all is the security: you should never be storing any password related stuff anywhere. The username should suffice. Browsers offer the possibility to remember passwords for given site. I would recommend you using this functionality instead of doing what you are doing.

Another possibility is to emit a persistent authentication cookie when the user logs in, so that even if he closes the browser he will be remembered as authenticated for the validity period you specified in this authentication cookie.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I now realized I had mistaken that feature as something to be coded when in fact its a browser feature. So I decided to leave it to the browser for the password. Decided to only store the username in the cookie to autofill the login box on next visit. I edited my code in the original post but I still think im doing something wrong. Please take a look, thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

you don't need the actual password for the user to make sure he logged in previously. You shouldn't even save the actual password in the database. You usually only save a salted hash of that password. When the user logs in, you create a hash for that password and compare it with the hash stored in the database. If they match, he entered the correct password.

As for storing login information in a cookie, i'd then store a salted hash of that password hash in the cookie. Upon GET, you just create a salted hash of the stored password hash and compare it with the one from the cookie. If they match, the login cookie is valid. That way you never actually store any user password anywhere.

To make this more secure, the login page should be secured by SSL, otherwise the password would at least once be transmitted unencrypted.

Answer (score -2):

If you're using SQL, you can generate a random number when the user first logs on. Store this number in the Users table, and also as a cookie on the user's machine. The user can then authenticate by comparing the random number with that stored on the server.

It's a good idea to timestamp the login though, so it expires after a set period of time.